# error while compling the metaprogram in prolog

Tags: prolog, logic, iso-prolog, prolog-metainterpreter

I am trying to implement a meta-program in ECLiPSe Prolog, and here's the code that i have written -

```
:- dynamic go/1.
sol(true):- !.
sol((A,B)):- !, sol(A), sol(B).
sol(A):- clause(A, Body), sol(Body).
go(X):- X is 5.
```

Now when I query with `sol(go(X)).` , I get the error `accessing a procedure defined in another module in clause(X is 5, _292)` and it aborts. I tried clearing all toplevel modules and reopening ECLiPSe and then running, but still the same error.

What could be the reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Predicate `p/1` is using the built-in predicate `(is)/2`. Note that `X is 5` is a syntactically more convenient way of writing `is(X,5)`. But your meta-interpreter is only expecting user defined predicates and the control constructs `(',')/2` and `true/0`. If you want to handle `(is)/2` you have to introduce a separate clause for it.

```
sol(X is Y) :- !, X is Y.
```

Within ISO Prolog, the goal `predicate_property(Goal,built_in)` can be used to test if `Goal` is a built-in predicate. This works in many systems like B, GNU, SICStus,  SWI, XSB, YAP.  So you can write:

```
sol(Bip) :- predicate_property(Bip, built_in), !, Bip.
```

In ECLiPSe this built-in is not directly available. You have to load a library. The [index of the manual](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/fullindex.html) suggests to use library `swi` or `quintus`.  For some (unclear) reason it is not part of the ECLiPSe library `iso`, yet it is ISO. So state

```
:- use_module(library(swi)).
```

in your file (or at the toplevel) first.

If you want a meta-interpreter to cover the full Prolog language you will have to handle all control constructs explicitly. Here they are - as defined in the standard (7.8 Control constructs).

1. `true/0`
2. `fail/0`
3. `call/1`
4. `!/0`
5. `(',')/2`
6. `(;)/2` - disjunction
7. `(->)/2`
8. `(;)/2` - if-then-else
9. `catch/3`
10. `throw/1`

Please be aware that only a few of them can be handled by directly calling the goal. Most of them must be handled explicitly!